# In Rails, how do I get contents of a file to render when I click on tabs using the jquery-ui tabs functonality?

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, tabs, partial

I’m using Rails 4.  I would like to have a tabbed interface and so I figured JQuery UI was up to the task.  However, what I would like is when a user clicks on each tab, the content from my partial view is rendered in that tab (div).  So my tabs, in my “app/views/admin/index.html.erb” file, currently display like so …

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="list">Current Objects</a></li>
    <li><a href="add">Add Object</a></li> 
    <li><a href="approve">Approve Objects</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="list"></div>

<div id="add"></div>

<div id="approve"></div>
```

I have these partial views

```
app/views/admin/_add.html.erb
app/views/admin/_list.html.erb
app/views/admin/_approve.html.erb
```

Then I have this in my app/assets/javascripts/admin.coffee file

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> $( "#tabs" ).tabs()
```

How do I click on each tab and get the contents of the contents above partial to render in the display region?  I have this in my controller currently,

```
  def list
    @page_id = "list"
    @my_objects = MyObject.all
    render "index"
  end

  def add
    @page_id = "add"
    @my_object = MyObject.new
    render "index"
  end

  def create
  end

  def approve
    @page_id = "approve"
    @my_objects = MyObject.where(enabled: [false, nil])
    render "index"
  end
```

but this doesn’t work.  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: JQuery is up to the task, but in Rails apps you have to include Ajax + "unobtrusive JavaScript" if you want the page content to change without reloading a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="list" id="list_tab" class="tab_anchors">Current Objects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="add" id="add_tab" class="tab_anchors">Add Object</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <a href="approve" id="approve_tab" class="tab_anchors">Approve Objects</a> 
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="list"></div>

<div id="add"></div>

<div id="approve"></div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.tab_anchors').click(function(){
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('id');
      if (tab_id == 'list_tab') {
        var url = '/list';
        var rendering_div = $('#list');
      } else if (tab_id == 'add_tab') {
        var url = '/add';
        var rendering_div = $('#add');
      }
      else{
        var url = '/approve';
        var rendering_div = $('#approve');
      }
     // Assuming the request is of 'GET' type.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
          rendering_div.html(data);
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

And change your controller like this:

```
  def list
    @page_id = "list"
    @my_objects = MyObject.all
    render :partial => "admin/list"
  end

  def add
    @page_id = "add"
    @my_object = MyObject.new
    render :partial => "admin/add"
  end

  def create
  end

  def approve
    @page_id = "approve"
    @my_objects = MyObject.where(enabled: [false, nil])
    render :partial => "admin/approve"
  end
```

Comment: Actually , render :partial was the only thing I needed and now the content is rendering.

Answer (score 0):

A far as i understand your problem, Instead of rendering index `render index`.

You remove `render index` and rails will automatically render your one of  3 partials that you mentioned in Question and in partial you can show the corresponding `div`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, This isn’t working.  When I comment out the ‘render “index”’ line from those methods and then click on a tab, I get these 500 errors in my logs, ‘ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admin/add, application/add with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :web_console_v2], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/views”’

Comment: Because you want to have some dynamic content, You have to make href pointing to url `/list` or `/add` or something( as no idea about your route file) and `remote: true` and as you are using jquery UI, so you can use data attribute to make corresponding tab active. see Doc of jquery UI to make tabs active by data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do something like

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="list">Current Objects</a></li>
    <li><a href="add">Add Object</a></li> 
    <li><a href="approve">Approve Objects</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
<% # if files do not live in the same direcotory %>
<div id="list"><%= render 'admin/list' %></div>
<div id="add"><%= render 'admin/add' %></div>
<div id="approve"><%= render 'admin/approve' %></div> 

<% # if files live in the same direcotory %>
<div id="list"><%= render 'list' %></div>
<div id="add"><%= render 'add' %></div>
<div id="approve"><%= render 'approve' %></div>
```